# Preload multiple Admob ads into an array?

Tags: android, gallery, admob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to preload AdMob ads on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319245/is-there-a-way-to-preload-admob-ads-on-android)

I've got a gallery of textviews, and I allow the user to flip between them. Each one shows a different Admob advertisement. The only problem is that there is a delay. It takes a few seconds for the Google ad to show up. Does anyone know how I could populate an array of ads upon app startup, asynchronously?

Comment: Are you flipping views with a ViewFlipper or?

Comment: Actually it's a Gallery of LinearLayouts, being flipped with the onFling method in Gallery.

Comment: I have done it by use one adview multiple time and in multiple activity,

It just load once, and you can use it where ever you want,
It will refresh on its given refresh rate.

demo is given here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29313641/2149195

Answer (score 0):

From the AdMob [content guidelines](http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/content-guidelines):

> Ads should not be pre-cached, cached, or stored in any fashion. All ads should be requested dynamically and, on mobile sites, refreshed when the page is refreshed.

And from a technical perspective, the SDK is written in such a way to try to not let you do this.  Banners are displayed as soon as the request is successful, and moving the AdView around in your layout is messy.

Comment: I want to make all the requests in a batch at app startup, and put them in an array for viewing later. Admob may not desire this kind of usage, but that's beside the point. I wonder if anyone can help me figure out how to accomplish it.