# Implementing admob for different activities

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I have three activities in total and i am implementing admob for each activity, every activity has its own banner and when the activity is changes the other activity hangs a little because of the ad loading in the background, is there any way that one banner appears in all the activities when switched to avoid delays.

Comment: The ad loads in a separate thread naturally, out of the box. in all my apps, I load the ad in concrete and then display it when fully loaded.

Answer (score 23):

you can do it just load ad in application class and
use it in any activity.

you can download [demo](http://ravikoradiya.com/android/AdCacheDemo/AdCache.zip)

as I do it,

App class

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class App extends Application {

AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate();

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1267746788642565/8418489933");
    // Request for Ads
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

public void loadAd(LinearLayout layAd) {

    // Locate the Banner Ad in activity xml
    if (adView.getParent() != null) {
        ViewGroup tempVg = (ViewGroup) adView.getParent();
        tempVg.removeView(adView);
    }

    layAd.addView(adView);

}
}
```

main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

App app;
LinearLayout layAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layAd = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layad);

    app = (App) getApplication();
    app.loadAd(layAd);

    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent iNext = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(iNext);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    app.loadAd(layAd);
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

Second Activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

App app;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    LinearLayout layAd = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layad);

    app = (App) getApplication();
    app.loadAd(layAd);
}
}
```

Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admobdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.admobdemo.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.admobdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.admobdemo.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

main activity layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and second activity layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Effort for explaining appreciated but it shows error at my place

Comment: @RaviKoradiya can I use layout for AdView here in 'Application' class?

Comment: tried like [this](http://paste.ofcode.org/4GP7pFhPss5MScM3UzNqDR) but its reloading ad again and again on switching between activities

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The key is maintaining the instance of the AdView in a static class or central instance class like Application and then its just a matter of dynamically Adding/Removing the AdView from Activity's controls/widget tree view as is shown in loadAd method above. Thanks @RBK

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way is to use fragments for each of your `screens`. This way, you'd use a single activity having a single adview.

If you want to use multiple activities instead, then the only workaround I know of is to use a static method to load the ads:

```
public class MyAdView {
    public static void SetAD(AdView adView){  
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private AdView adView;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.caller_main);
        MyAdView.SetAd((AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView));
    }   
}
```

Comment: the best approach to keep long admob-related codes away from activities! thank you, but does it make sense to make it static ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this was answered a long time ago, but I think I have a better way for when you've already created your entire app with many activities. While RBK's solution is really good, it requires you to go through each activity's layout file and add the following LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

However, this can get really tedious if you have lots of different activities with lots of different layout files (especially if you're like me and forgot about admob integration until you finished the majority of the app). The simple improvement I found was creating a subclass of `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` which handles placement and loading of the ads:

So similarly to RBK's solution, we create an Application class **App**. However, this will have a few small changes. Instead of placing our banner ad in a specific ViewGroup (like `layad`) in our activites, we want it be automatically added to the bottom of an activity without us having to add anything to the layout file. We replace `loadAd` with a method that does this.

```
public class App extends Application {

    AdView adView;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate();

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        // Request for Ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Load ads into Banner Ads
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    // run by each activity to show the banner ad on the bottom
    public void addBannerAdToActivity(AD_ACTIVITY context) {
        // get the root linear layout. We'll insert our banner ad at the end of it
        LinearLayout rootView = context.getRootLayout();

        // if the banner already has a parent, remove it...
        if (adView.getParent() != null) {
            ViewGroup par = (ViewGroup) adView.getParent();
            par.removeView(adView);
        }

        // set 'rootView' as the new parent of the banner:
        rootView.addView(adView);

        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // just incase the banner isn't visible for some reason

        // Now the ad will be placed on the bottom of the activity requesting it
    }
}
```

Then we create an abstract class **AD_ACTIVITY** that extends `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public abstract class AD_ACTIVITY extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private LinearLayout root;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // The content view of an AD_ACTIVITY is a linear layout with the first element being the main content and the second element being the banner ad:
        root = new LinearLayout(this); // create a new LinearLayout
        root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
   
        super.setContentView(root); // set that as the content view...
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        // Inflate the layout file and get a reference to it:
        ViewGroup inflatedView = (ViewGroup) ((LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID,root)).getChildAt(0);
        
        // we want the main content to take up the whole vertical screen with space at the bottom for the banner ad
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.weight = 1; // to do this, we set the weight of 'inflatedView' to 1
        inflatedView.setLayoutParams(params);

        // LOAD BANNER AD AND ADD IT TO 'root':
        ((App) getApplicationContext()).addBannerAdToActivity(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // LOAD BANNER AD AND ADD IT TO 'root':
        ((App) getApplicationContext()).addBannerAdToActivity(this);
    }

    public LinearLayout getRootLayout() {
        return root;
    }
}
```

Now all we do is go through all activities and have it extend `AD_ACTIVITY` instead of `AppCompatActivity`. For example:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Gets changed to:

```
public class MainActivity extends AD_ACTIVITY {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Changing the position of the banner, its behavior, and position is extremly easy to do since any changes done to `AD_ACTIVITY` will apply to all activities extending it.