# Using same loaded AdMob on multiple activities

Tags: android, admob

I have an application in which you can open unlimited number of activities, it's like article app, every time you click on an article a new activity is created. I am using this code to load AdMob ads

```
AdView adView = new AdView(context);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(Config(context, "banner_unit_id"));
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

if(adView.getAdSize() != null || adView.getAdUnitId() != null){
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Now what I want to do is use the same loaded ad on multiple activities, so the ad won't have to be loaded again and again on every single activity. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: - Hey take one fragmentActivity. Load the add in it and you will load unlimited number of fragment in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this without breaking something else.

The recommended way of achieving what you are after is to load up your content in new Fragments and keep a single Activity intact in which to display them.

Answer (score 1):

you can it just load ad in application class and
use it in any activity.

actual [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29313641/2149195)

as I do it,

App class

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class App extends Application {

AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate();

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1267746788642565/8418489933");
    // Request for Ads
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

public void loadAd(LinearLayout layAd) {

    // Locate the Banner Ad in activity xml
    if (adView.getParent() != null) {
        ViewGroup tempVg = (ViewGroup) adView.getParent();
        tempVg.removeView(adView);
    }

    layAd.addView(adView);

}
}
```

main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

App app;
LinearLayout layAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layAd = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layad);

    app = (App) getApplication();
    app.loadAd(layAd);

    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent iNext = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(iNext);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    app.loadAd(layAd);
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

Second Activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

App app;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    LinearLayout layAd = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layad);

    app = (App) getApplication();
    app.loadAd(layAd);
}
}
```

Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admobdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.admobdemo.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.admobdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.admobdemo.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

main activity layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and second activity layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```