# How to Hide Ad View in Recycler View

Tags: java, android, admob, android-recyclerview

I have implemented Admob Native Express ads in my Recycler View. Its keeping blank space in list till advertise getting loaded as well if there no internet available. How can I hide that blank space till advertise get loaded ?
Thanks

Comment: you can cache ad, so you need to load ad once, no need to load ad every time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29313641/2149195

Answer (score 1):

Just implement an [AdListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html) that listen to the `onAdLoaded` event.

> The `onAdLoaded` method is executed when an **ad has finished loading. If you want to delay adding the AdView to your activity or fragment until you're sure an ad will be loaded, for example, you can do so here**. If you're using a third-party analytics package to track impressions, this is also where you can place the call to record one.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/ad-events#setting_up_an_adlistener)

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // HERE!!!!!!
    }
});
```

**NOTE** it's not necessary to [override all methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/banner#smart_banners)

> AdListener provides a default empty implementation for all of its ad lifecycle events. You only need to override the ad events you wish to implement.

Comment: Hi ! Its showing ads after load as you have told, but still showing blank space of advertise in my list, I want hide it. want make view.GONE. my developer telling that view.GONE is not working in RecyclerView. its true ?