# Adding Admob for Different Activities Using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android development and was trying to add ADMOB for an application with 16 activities. I have already searched this over the stackflow and found a solution here at [Implementing admob for different activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304697/implementing-admob-for-different-activities) but this solution is not quite easy or understandable for beginners. I heard someone that I can implement it using fragments.

Comment: You should try to understand the answer of @RBK in the former question, the solution seems correct.

Comment: @Xvolks Can I know what is this thing named second activity in his comment?

Comment: It’s just a sample activity to show you how to implement your thing on other activities.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, one last thing how can I create/find app class?