# Sometime AdMob Banner and interstitial does not load

Tags: android, admob

I have finance application on google play and I have 800 active users per day in the app. Some time AdMob banner and interstitialAd does not load and it shows white banner in place of the ad. Java code below :

```
 AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                   .addTestDevice("CA626566A7B365501AE304BBA64A11D9")
                   .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

test.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

AdsUtil.java
// This is my interstitialAd java class when user back any screen then i call showInterstitial(); .

```
public class AdsUtil {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private Context context;

    public AdsUtil(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();
    }

    private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
        InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));

        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
//                mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
//                mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Proceed to the next level.
                goToNextLevel();
            }
        });
        return interstitialAd;
    }

    public void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
        if(!Utility.getSharedPreferencesBoolean(context, Constant.isPrimeUser) && Constant.adsFlag ) {

            Constant.adsFlag=false;
            timerAds();


            if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                goToNextLevel();
            }

        }
    }

    private void loadInterstitial() {
        // Disable the next level button and load the ad.
//        mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
//                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    private void goToNextLevel() {
        // Show the next level and reload the ad to prepare for the level after.
//        mLevelTextView.setText("Level " + (++mLevel));
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();
    }

    private void timerAds(){
        new CountDownTimer(1000*10*1, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Constant.adsFlag=true;
            }
        }.start();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of 2 reasons,

1. The network will take time to load the AD as it is being requested on activity open.
   To solve this, you have to preload the ADs on app starting and request to display on a particular activity where you need to display this.
2. It also depends on the internet connectivity. There will be some delay because of the internet connectivity.

Comment: No i have wifi connection .

Comment: Even though you are working on Wi-Fi connection, the request and response time to load the ad will take time. So pre load the ad and call on the transition in between activities. You can follow this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304697/implementing-admob-for-different-activities/29313641#29313641

Comment: how do you preload the ads?